# Define a Matlab-like .* operator in C++?

Tags: c++, matlab, operators

Matlab is able to distinguish between 'proper' matrix multiplication and element-wise matrix multiplication with different operators, so that the former is done as `A * B` and the latter as `A .* B`.  This is pretty convenient and I was wondering if there was a way to achieve the same thing in C++ for a custom matrix class (and likewise for `./` and `.^`).  That is, I was wondering if it is possible, through defining macros or any other method, to have something like the following actually compile:

```
MyMatrix A(2,3), B(2,3), C(2,3); //These are 2x3 matrices for the sake of concreteness
C = A .* B; //Similarly for ./, .^
```

I tried doing this with some simple function `#define`s and couldn't get it to work, so I figured I'd put it to SO.  I can accept 'near misses', i.e. if `.*` can't work but somehow `:*` can, good enough.  NB, I'm specifically looking for operators--of course, this behavior can be accomplished with functions in the obvious way but Matlab-like operators would be pretty convenient.

Comment: If you find this "pretty convenient" you're apparently not using your matrices for the "normal" purpose – linear operators, with `*` as composition – but for something else, where `*` as matrix multiplication probably doesn't make too much sense. So you probably want two different classes, one for linear-map-matrices and one for elementwise-matrices, each with its own `operator*`. You can add explicit or implicit conversion functions if you need to go from one representation to the other.   This way it's not only going to be more self-explanatory, but also safer than the Matlab version.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Are you familiar with Matlab?  The situation exists there as I described it.  In any case, having worked with Matlab (and matrices) a lot, there are certainly situations in which, for a given matrix, you will at one point want to do standard matrix multiplication on it, and at another, some element-wise operation.  So this would be handy.

Comment: As far as I know, `.*`  in matlab is to do scalar multiplication which is distinguished from matrix multiplication. In C++, you can totally use one operator `*` and do operator/function overloading.

Comment: Well, it's not a surprise that such stuff can be handy in Matlab where the focus is much "everything is a matrix" (IMHO a mathematically unappealing point of view: matrices are extremely handy but not so much for their own sake but for _representing_ more abstract concepts). It's not necessarily a good thing. Even if you have one matrix at one point involved in a matrix multiplication and at another point in an elementwise multiplication, the matrices you're multiplying _with_ have almost certainly quite different meaning, and should therefore have different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I'm really suggesting this be done (it's an abomination).  You could, say, create a small wrapper class, that when multiplied by a matrix performs an elementwise multiplication.  Then give the matrix class a `element_wise()` method, which returns such a wrapper.  Then, you cold "create" operators `_*`, `_/`, etc:

```
#define _ .element_wise()

A = B _* C; // really B.element_wise() * C
```

Or keep the preprocessor out of it, by giving each matrix such a wrapper at construction and calling it `_`, thus allowing:

```
A = B ._* C;
B = A ._/ C;
```

Comment: This is a horrible suggestion. Macros are almost never the way to go, and defining `_` as a macro is asking for trouble. I, in particular, use `_` for *don't care about* arguments, and this macro would break my code in many different ways.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas Doesn't hist answer start with "Not that I'm really suggesting this be done"? It's a *hypothetical* solution. And really, if your code breaks with this macro, that's really not a problem with this macro :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: Macros break code, and the problem is that there is some perfectly working code out there that would stop working if such a macro is defined. You might not consider this an issue, but think that I could just `#define i *complex<double>(0.,1.)` to make code more math like: `complex<double> a = 5 i;` If you use `i` as a variable is your problem... my macro is fine! What about `#define T typedef`, it makes my type definitions nicer! Seriously, macros should be avoided in general, and macros that don't have a name following convention (all upper case, long name) more so.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas You're describing masking. This is a problem not unique to macros, i.e., masking can also occur when including two different libraries with the same classname and signature etc.. The difference is that in the latter case, the compiler can more easily such problems. You dislike macros, and me too. But you should hate them because they are more likely to introduce bugs, not for the fact that they break code. That is a problem with *your code*, not with macros in general.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: The problem with macros is that they don't respect the rest of the code, and that is not the same problem as *masking* in general, since I can have my code in my own namespaces so that symbols defined in third party libraries will not affect my code. But **macros** in those libraries break the code in other parts of the system. You might not consider this to be an issue, but if you google for macro problems I bet most places where they recommend not using macros is because they can break other code introducing bugs.

Comment: ... I am actually surprised at your stance... it seems that breaking other people's code is not your problem but the problem of the other programmers whose code breaks. Say that a library defined 'NULL' to be, say `1`, rather than `0` (C++, note that NULL is not a keyword), now whose problem is it that *any* code that uses that library and `NULL` fails to compile? Is it my problem because I use NULL? or is it the problem of whoever decided that `NULL` could be redefined to be something else? Note that the problem is not that it breaks **my** code, but that it breaks **other unrelated code**.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas Look, I'm just pushing you a bit. We agree, no worries. I just wanted to check if you discourage and dislike macros for the right reasons. I just can't stand the often-used "do this so and so, because it's generally better". Statements like those make me all itchy! What matters here on SO is that you explain **WHY** those things are better, and try to include **ALL** such reasons. I was just missing the part about the ease with which bugs are introduced by macros. If the code breaks, it is not a bug -- in that case, it is a problem correctly detected by the compiler

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14955/discussion-between-rody-oldenhuis-and-david-rodriguez-dribeas)

Comment: Brilliant!  I might actually use the non-macro version.  Knew SO would come through for me!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a technique that is similar to Managu's answer only without the use of macros...

```
struct Mat;
struct EleWise {
  EleWise(){}
  double mat[3][3];
};

struct Mat {
  Mat(){}

  friend Mat operator / ( EleWise& e, const Mat& m ) 
  { 
     return Mat(); // perform elewise divide
  }
  EleWise _;
};


int main( int argc, char** arg ) {
  Mat a;
  Mat b;

  Mat c = a ._/ b;
  return 0;
};
```